# Unpivot Data Using MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, union, unpivot

Hoping someone with Access & SQL experience would be able to write some SQL code that I could use in MS Access to transform/unpivot some data. I've spent a day trying advise from others who have asked similar questions here, but I have no SQL experience and have failed miserably so far.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your sample data set and expected outcome as an example.

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking. Then, make an earnest attempt at solution and come back with *specific* issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` to unpivot in access:

```
select item, 'A' as period, a as forecast from tbl_weekly_forecast
union all select item, 'B', b from tbl_weekly_forecast
union all select item, 'C', c from tbl_weekly_forecast
union all select item, 'D', d from tbl_weekly_forecast
```